# Помощь в регулярном выражени

Tags: php

нужна помощь в регулярном выражении а именно:
Вот так скрипт работает в норме:

```
function callbackFunction( $matches) {
  echo $matches[1]."\n"; 
  echo $matches[2]."\n"; 
  echo $matches[3]."\n"; 
}

$pattern = '!\\[hide=([0-9,]+),user=(.+?)\\](.+?)\\[\\/hide\\]!is';
$subject = '[hide=3,user=test1,test2]rgqgefrefe[/hide]';
print_r(preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'callbackFunction', $subject, -1));
```

Вывод

```
3
test1,test2
rgqgefrefe
```

если же мы убираем в субъекте user, код не работает

```
$subject = '[hide=3]rgqgefrefe[/hide]';
```

Мне нужно что бы хайд работал как с `[hide=цифра,user=логин]`, а так же по раздельности как `[hide=1]` так и `[hide=login1,login2]` и что бы результат был как

```
1
user1,user2
rgqgefrefe
```

Comment: Для начала сформулируйте, какую именно строку вы ищете и что вы с ней хотите сделать?

Comment: Мне нужно что бы хайд работал как с [hide=цифра,user=логин], а так же по раздельности как [hide=1] так и [user=login1,login2] и что бы результат был как /* result:1
user1,user2
rgqgefrefe*/

Comment: А для `[user=login1,login2]` закрывающий тег должен быть `[/user]`?

Comment: ну смотри, вот допустим хайд для форума, [hide=цифра сообщения, user=логины или логин]текст[/hide] а если допустим только логин то [hide=test]текст[/hide ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как у вас вот эта часть `user=test1,test2` не обязательна, то было бы лучше использовать именованные подмаски. Шаблон будет выглядеть так:

```
\[hide=(?<hide>.+?)(?:,\s?user=(?<user>.+))?](?<text>.+?)\[/hide]
```

Код лучше записать с использованием preg_match_all():

```
$str = '[hide=3, user=текст1, текст2]текст[/hide]';
//$str = '[hide=hide]текст[/hide]'; // Этот вариант тоже рабочий

$patt = '~\[hide=(?<hide>.+?)(?:,\s?user=(?<user>.+))?](?<text>.+?)\[/hide]~';
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr['hide'], $arr['user'], $arr['text']);
```

Comment: NULL NULL array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "i" [1]=> string(6) "=3, us" [2]=> string(2) "=t" [3]=> string(5) "t1, t" [4]=> string(14) "t2]текст[" [5]=> string(1) "i" } вот ответ с данной функции, что то не то

Comment: @GDRest смотрим **[сюда](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a91b7eb45c455fe8fb30d51097e685ae1bac8ef5)**

Comment: а если по отдельности не в дампе? echo var_dump($arr['hide']); // NULL
//echo $arr['user'];
//echo $arr['text']; что то не выходит

Comment: @GDRest это же массивы, а значит надо не `var_dump($arr['hide']);`, а вот так: `echo $arr['hide'][0], $arr['user'][0], $arr['text'][0];`. Ну или в цикле каждый массив распечатывать при необходимости. Задача ведь в поиске и получении необходимых подстрок, а не в их обработке.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/66504715fb3bf13c471ce27c9d99376ff7d74c1d а если допустим в таком виде, в функции как правильно будет?

Comment: @GDRest а зачем вы туда функцию прикрутили? o_O ... Я же вам дал готовое решение, Для строки `<p>
Как вы относитесь ко всему вышесказанному? Любите античит от Рокстар, который банит честных игроков?)</p>
<p>
 [hide=3, user=test2]rgqgefrefe[/hide]
</p>` оно так же исправно работает. [Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ff63be24a1824267c3fc596c7ac7e865f831e0e)

Comment: потому что в коде надо через функцию делать, http://prntscr.com/jazktc что бы  не затрагивать весь код

Comment: @GDRest вы не в состоянии скопировать рабочий код и вставить его в тело метода `content()`? Или в чём ещё проблема? Почитайте мануал, если вам не понятна суть работы pcre-функций, там всё описано в примерах. А тут в комментариях не принято давать ответы, и более того на ваш вопрос уже есть корректный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое !!

Comment: Смотрите, а вот так не работает, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b99152fba888944310bc3a64ab21925b1cc19e7 http://prntscr.com/jb9sl2

Comment: @GDRest добавьте модификатор `s` : `'~\[hide=(?<hide>.+?)(?:,\s?user=(?<user>.+))?](?<text>.+?)\[/hide]~s'`

Comment: Работает, спасибо большое!